# How can I stop MAMP PRO from creating index.php and MAMP-PRO-Logo.gif files in all of my hosts every time it restarts Apache?

Tags: mamp

It's not a big deal, but it's annoying. Is there a way to disable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create or reference a directory with existing contents, MAMP Pro won't override these files with the placeholder.

Placeholder contents can be found in: `/Applications/MAMP\ PRO/MAMP\ PRO.app/Contents/Resources/placeholder/`

You could try removing these files from the placeholder directory and see if that works for you.

Comment: @bernk, be sure to mark the answer as solved/chosen if it worked for you.

Comment: In Windows : C:\MAMP\bin\vhostdata

Comment: If I remove those files out of the placeholder-folder, I cannot start MAMP after rebooting the machine (Program is corrupted). I really have to reinstall MAMP to get it working again. Seems that it is not allowed to directly edit the "app" folder.